# Can't connect to SQL Server with Windows authentication with my ASP.NET Core application (IIS server)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, iis, windows-authentication

I have a problem when I deploy my ASP.NET Core 3.1 application to IIS.

When I provide Windows credentials in the `appsettings.json` file, I always get this error:

> Login failed with DOMAIN\USERNAME$

Should I update the connection string in my `web.config` or update my IIS Server in IIS Manager ?

`appsettings.json`:

```xml
{
    "AppSettings": {
        "Secret": "9HGXuFLr5PeSjhBBgvMM8CYCQkCcfFgWgQFQvX9M6ahsHC87ESH3cVajpnfTHEBJ"
    },
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Debug",
            "System": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Information"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*",
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "L4LAuthentification_TEST01DataBase": "Server=SRVSQL-01-TST\\INSTANCE1;Database=L4LAuthentification_TEST01;Integrated Security=True;",
        "L4Authentification_RECET01DataBase": "Server=SRVSQL-01-TST\\INSTANCE1;Database=L4Authentification_RECET01;Integrated Security=True;",
        "DevInfoCDataBase": "Server=SRVSQL-01-TST\\INSTANCE1;Database=DevInfoC;Integrated Security=True;",
        "InfocentreRecet01DataBase": "Server=SRVSQL-01-TST\\INSTANCE1;Database=InfocentreRecet01;Integrated Security=True;",
        "L4LGestionFLux_TEST01DataBase": "Server=SRVSQL-01-TST\\INSTANCE1;Database=L4LGestionFLux_TEST01;Integrated Security=True;",
        "L4GestionFlux_RECET01DataBase": "Server=SRVSQL-01-TST\\INSTANCE1;Database=L4GestionFlux_RECET01;Integrated Security=True;",
        "L4EdiFluxInDataBase": "Server=SRVSQL-01-TST\\INSTANCE1;Database=L4EdiFluxIn;Integrated Security=True;",
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my comments to an Answer, since it did seem to put you on the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you use "Integrated Security=True", you need to know which identity (aka principal) your code is running. And that IIdentity (running your process in IIS) has to have credentials to the SqlServer. –

Most likely, your IIS runs your Application as "DOMAIN\USERNAME$".
And (correspondingly) the account DOMAIN\USERNAME$ does not have credentials to your ms-sql-server.

More than likely, you will create a more isolated "service account" that you will use to run your IIS Application AND that has permissions to your Ms-Sql-Server.

Comment: Thank you, I updated my Identity in the application pool (Advanced settings) to use my windows account and it worked !

Answer (score 1):

If `Integrated Security = True` doesn't work, you need to change Application pool in IIS.

1. Go to Application Pools-> Select your application-> Advance settings.
2. In Process Model Select Identity and select Custom account.
3. Add your machine credential into it and save.
4. Open command prompt in administrator mode and run command `iisreset`

Try to run your application again and it should work.