# ASP Error: SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$'. When trying to launch ASP page

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

This had been working fine in our prior server Windows 2012. New server is 2019.

IIS Setup:

- DefaultAppPool using ApplicationPoolIdentity as its identity.
- Anonymous and Windows Authentication enabled.

Both prior and current server hitting same SQL Server.

When we try launching the ASP Page, we get this error:

> SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$'.

In other posts I've read that it could be the connection string Trusted Connection setting that is incorrect, but the connection string is built inside the page code and it's never changed.

We've also read that since ApplicationPoolIdentity uses NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE as its user, then we'd need to add that service account to the SQL Server.

Again, it had been fine without it in the prior server. But just to try it, we added it to the User list as DB_OWNER in SQL Server.

But still get same error.

Connecting to the SQL server outside of this scenario is no an issue, we can get to it in SSMS and otherwise.

Any ideas and help appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73420867/214977

Comment: Yeah we had seen that and tried it , it worked. But like I said, we never had to do that before, it was fine without it.

Comment: `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` is not a real account. On the network it will act as the machine itself. So you need to give permissions to the `DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$` account. Alternatively run the app pool under a separate user account, and give that permissions on SQL Server.

Comment: "This had been working fine in our prior server Windows 2012" is never a valid excuse. To host a web app on IIS with database connections, the rule of thumb is to use a dedicated service account as application pool identity and then allow that account to log in to your database instance. Using ApplicationPoolIdentity or NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE is not really recommended as that expands the attacking surface unnecessarily and increases security risks.

Answer (score 0):

If you see a failure like this: `Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$'`. It means that a process running as `NETWORK SERVICE` or `LocalSystem` accessed a remote resource, authenticated itself as a machine account and was denied authorization. When access to the machine account is denied, the machine account must be granted access. If the server denies login to `'DOMAIN\MACHINE$'`, then you must grant login permission to `'DOMAIN\MACHINE$'` instead of `NETWORK SERVICE`.